# Sum of Series of Binomial Coefficients.

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Find the sum of $\binom{200k}{0}+\binom{200k}{100}+\binom{200k}{200}+...+\binom{200k}{200k}$ and $\binom{200k}{1}+\binom{200k}{101}+\binom{200k}{201}+...+\binom{200k}{200k-99}$ in terms of $k$.

I've tried to do generating functions but I don't get to make the terms cancel out for some reason. This problems seems quite well known but I do not know what terms to search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We consider the generating series $F(x)$ with
>   \begin{align*}
> F(x)=(1+x)^{200k}=\sum_{m=0}^{200k}\binom{200k}{m}x^{m}
> \end{align*}

In order to pick every $100$-th term of the generating series we use the $100$-th roots of unity
\begin{align*}
\omega_j=e^{\frac{2j\pi }{100}i}\qquad\qquad 0\leq j < 100
\end{align*}
and the relationship
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{100}\sum_{j=0}^{99}\omega^n_j=
\begin{cases}1&100|n\\0&\text{else}\end{cases}\qquad\qquad n>0\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{100}\sum_{j=0}^{99}F_k(\omega_j x)&=\frac{1}{100}\sum_{j=0}^{99}(1+\omega_jx)^{200k}\\
> &=\frac{1}{100}\sum_{j=0}^{99}\sum_{m=0}^{200k}\binom{200k}{m}(\omega_jx)^{m}\\
> &=\frac{1}{100}\sum_{m=0}^{200k}\binom{200k}{m}x^m\sum_{j=0}^{99}\omega_j^{m}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{m=0}^{2k}\binom{200k}{100m}x^{100m}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we rearrange the sums and use the cancellation property of the roots of unity from (1).

> Setting $x=1$ we conclude
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{m=0}^{2k}\binom{200k}{100m}=\sum_{j=0}^{99}(1+e^{\frac{2j\pi }{100}i})^{200k}
> \end{align*}

*Hint:* For the second sum consider
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{100}\sum_{j=0}^{99}\left(\omega_j\right)^{-1}(1+\omega_jx)^{200k}
\end{align*}

Comment: Is there a closed form of the answer - not in a summation form?

Comment: I think the (1) of your answer is incorrect. Setting n=100 makes your quantity 101/100. Did you mean to take the summation only from 0 to 99?

Comment: @TheMathTroll: You're right of course. Typo corrected.

Comment: @TheMathTroll: I'm not aware of a more compact formulation. You may want to look at example 4 on page 51  in  H.Wilf's  *[Generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfology2.pdf)*.